# Generating Platforms without Pygame Sprite class

Tags: python, pygame

How can I go about generating platforms to corresponding "E"'s of the `level` *without* the `Sprite` class?  I tried some different methods but none of them seemed to work.  Basically, the idea is that the "E"'s should just make 50x50 blocks in a row.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width = 900
display_height = 600
size = (display_width, display_height)


black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

platx = 350
platy = 150
platw = 50
plath = 50

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


platx = 600
platy = 350
platw = 50
plath = 50


level = ["E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E"]


class Platform:
    def __init__(self, platx, platy, platw, plath):
        self.platx = platx
        self.platy = platy
        self.platw = platw
        self.plath = plath

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [self.platx, self.platy, self.platw, self.plath])

platforms = Platform(platx, platy, platw, plath)

game_exit = False

while not game_exit:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True
    #why doesnt a loop like this work?
    #for i in level:
    #    if i == "E":
    #        platforms.draw()    
    #    platx += display_width *.1
    #shouldn't it be placing platforms 1/10 of the display_width from the starting platx?

    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, this is the code that needs to be fixed:

```
#why doesnt a loop like this work?
    #for i in level:
    #    if i == "E":
    #        platforms.draw()    
    #    platx += display_width *.1
    #shouldn't it be placing platforms 1/10 of the display_width from the starting platx?
```

The problem with this is that `platx` was already passed as an argument to `Platform.__init__`. Since the variable `platform.platx` no longer has a weakref to the global `platx` (being passed as an argument), they no longer match. Thus, instead of incrementing `platx`, `platform.platx should be incremented.

Also, you need to reset `platform.platx` after drawing each row.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. Any suggestions to how I should reset `platform.platx`?

Comment: Just set it to some value using `=` after the second loop. That is for you to decide exactly how.